Tkinter place geometry manager not overlapping
Over the past several years I've been using a full-featured combobox widget that I made by stitching together other Tkinter widgets. (Because I like it better than ttk.Combobox.) For the dropdown I've always used a Toplevel widget since it overlaps other widgets instead of pushing them aside. I've never been able to get the place geometry manager to work as the dropdown, it won't overlap the other widgets. I know that some people say never use place() for anything anyway, but I just have to satisfy my curiosity as to whether it would be easier to use a placed Frame instead of using a borderless Toplevel window.
But I can't get the placed Frame to overlap at all, so can someone tell me what's wrong with this simple sample code, why doesn't the dropdown overlap other widgets? As soon as its rely is set to 1, it becomes invisible, covered by the other widgets.
import tkinter as tk

def unplace():
    dropdown.place_forget()

def show(evt=None):
    dropdown.lift()
    dropdown.place(relx=0, rely=0.3, anchor='nw', relwidth=1.0)#rely=1, 
    # dropdown.place(relx=0, rely=1, anchor='nw', relwidth=1.0)
    dropdown_item.grid(sticky="ew")

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400+600+300")
root.config(bg="red")
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

frm = tk.Frame(root, bg="blue")
frm.grid(sticky="news")

ent = tk.Entry(frm)
ent.grid()
ent.bind("<Button-1>", show)

dropdown = tk.Frame(ent, bg="tan")
dropdown_item = tk.Button(
    dropdown, bg="steelblue", width=12, command=unplace, text="item")
# If these labels are commented, `dropdown` still won't overlap.
c = tk.Label(frm, text="Overlap Me")
c.grid()
d = tk.Label(frm, text="Overlap Me")
d.grid()
e = tk.Label(frm, text="Overlap Me")
e.grid()
f = tk.Label(frm, text="Overlap Me")
f.grid()

show()

root.mainloop()


«I know that some people say never use place() for anything» - these people are completely wrong. The place method is just rarely used, since in 99% of cases the other 2 methods are more appropriate, but there are situations when it does its job much better than the others. Your situation might be one of those.

You should not create dropdown as child of ent.  Suggest to use parent of ent as the parent of dropdown instead.  Then calculate the pop-up position based on the position of ent instead of hard-coded relative position.

@acw1668 Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try it later today.

In regards to the main goal underlying this inquiry, I just realized that a placed Frame lacks one feature which Toplevel widgets have. A placed widget won't display outside the boundaries of the Tkinter app, whereas the Toplevel will display anywhere on the screen. Unless I'm wrong, I'll be rolling back to the Toplevel for my combobox dropdown.

When I followed the suggestions in @acw1668's comment, I found that I had misunderstood x and y. They are positions relative to the parent, not the screen. Making the entry and the dropdown siblings in the same parent, instead of putting the dropdown inside the entry and then trying to shift it, was the first step.
import tkinter as tk

def unplace():
    dropdown.place_forget()

def show(evt=None):
    root.update_idletasks()
    ht = ent.winfo_height()
    x = ent.winfo_x()
    y = ent.winfo_y() + ht
    dropdown.place(x=x, y=y, anchor='nw')
    dropdown.lift()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400+600+300")
root.config(bg="red")
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

frm = tk.Frame(root, bg="blue")
frm.grid(sticky="news")

ent = tk.Entry(frm)
ent.grid()

dropdown = tk.Frame(frm)
item = tk.Button(
    dropdown, width=12, command=unplace, text="item", bd=0, bg="dark gray")
item.grid()
ent.bind("<Button-1>", show)

c = tk.Label(frm, text="Overlap Me")
c.grid()
d = tk.Label(frm, text="Overlap Me")
d.grid()
e = tk.Label(frm, text="Overlap Me")
e.grid()
f = tk.Label(frm, text="Overlap Me")
f.grid()

root.mainloop()


Better use ent.winfo_height() instead of ent.winfo_reqheight() because they may not be the same.  Also you don't need to call item.grid() inside show(), call it just after creating the button item.
